# has any more MVCObject demo ?(google maps v3)

Tags: model-view-controller, google-maps, demo

i have a demo : http://code.google.com/intl/zh-CN/apis/maps/articles/mvcfun.html

but ,  i can't understand clearly ,

so has any more demo about it ,

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a step-by-step tutorial [here](http://tech.cibul.net/drag-and-drop-two-markers-linked-with-a-line-on-google-maps-v3/) using MVCObject to link two draggable markers with a line

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Marc Ridey's Blog](http://blog.mridey.com/2010/03/maps-javascript-api-v3-more-about.html)

Doing a google search turned up a few as well: [Google Search](http://www.google.com/search?q=google+maps+MVCObject+examples&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)

I feel your pain!  Going thru the same problems with almost a total lack of good documentation on the subject.. Google's answer is that not many developers with need to use it.. lol

[image]